# Disable IIS7 Compression for a single file from web.config

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

Does anyone know a way of disabling compression for a single file using the web.config file?  It is possible to achieve this manually via the IIS7 management console, but I would much rather configure this from the application's web.config file.

Comment: I think it's an serverfault question

Comment: I disagree.  The reason I needed to bake the setting into the application web.config file is so the system admins don't need to remember or even know about this application specific bit of configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use management console, and after edit web.config and see changes.